# onActivityResult - data string returns null

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have problem with onActiviResult function. Code compiles and emulates but the data parameter returns null.

In function main:

```
private static String sActualLogin = "admin";
private static String sActualPassword = "qwerty";

(...)

public void setRegisterOnClick(View v)
    {
        Intent intentLOGIN = new Intent(this, Users.class);
        intentLOGIN.putExtra("Type",1);
        startActivityForResult(intentLOGIN, 1);
    }

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(data.getExtras().containsKey("Login")){
        if(resultCode==RESULT_OK && requestCode==1){
            String sContainer = data.getStringExtra("Login");
                sActualLogin=sContainer;
                RESULT1.setText(sActualLogin);
            }
        }

    if(data.getExtras().containsKey("Password")){
        if(resultCode==RESULT_OK && requestCode==1){
            String sContainer=data.getStringExtra("Password");
                sActualPassword=sContainer;
                RESULT2.setText(sActualPassword);
            }
        }
        }
```

And then code goes to Users:

```
package com.example.login;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Users extends Activity {

    private EditText etNewLogin;
    private EditText etNewPassword; 
    private TextView RESULT3; 

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.users);
        etNewLogin = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etChangeLogin);
        etNewLogin = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etChangePassword);
        RESULT3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.RESULT3);

        Intent Intent2=getIntent();
        int number = Intent2.getIntExtra("Type", 0);
        RESULT3.setText("" +number); //returns 1 well
    }

    public void giveResponse(View v)
    {   
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        int iOperation = intent.getIntExtra("Type", 0);

        if (iOperation == 1){
             String sNewLogin = etNewLogin.getText().toString();    
             intent.putExtra("Login", sNewLogin); 
             setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
             finish();
        }

        if (iOperation == 2){
             String sNewPassword = etNewPassword.getText().toString();
             intent.putExtra("Password", sNewPassword);    
             setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
             finish();
    }


    }
}
```

So I sActualLogin is being set to "" after onActivityResult. Please help me with this problem; something is wrong there and I can't see it.

Comment: where are you calling the `giveResponse` method? Also have you tried using breakpoints to see what data is passed inside the intents?

Comment: giveReponse is being called via button shown on Users activity. And I can easly send data from MainActivity -> Users inside intent. I'm checking it on RESULT3 TextView. But when I want to get my information back by setResult data recieves something, with "Login" label (because it goes inside if structure) but during isertion of string from data to temporary string sContainter it becomes null.

Comment: show us the stacktrace from your LogCat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming you start `Users` activity with `startActivityForResult(intent, 1);`, the only thing I see is that you set the same variable for both of the `EditText` views:

```
etNewLogin = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etChangeLogin);
etNewLogin = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etChangePassword);
```

You can also add to the `if` statement on `onActivityResult(...)` a check to make sure its not empty:

```
if(data.getExtras().containsKey("Login") && !data.getStringExtra("Login").isEmpty())
```